# The Python Windows launcher isn't reading `py.ini`

Tags: python, windows, pylauncher

I currently have Python 3.4 as my default Python version, but I want to set Python 2.7 as the default one temporarily.

I'm on Windows 7 and my Python scripts are run using the Python Windows launcher. [The documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#customization) I can customize it by creating a `py.ini` file, but that doesn't work. I created a file with these contents:

```
[defaults]
python=2.7
```

I've tried placing it in the same folder as the file I'm running, I tried placing it in `C:\Users\Administrator\`, in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\` and in `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\`, but none of these worked. The launcher still uses Python 3.4. (Both when I double-click the file in the Windows UI and both when I launch the launcher directly, like `py my_file.py`.)

**Why is the Python Windows launcher ignoring my `py.ini` file?**

Here's the output from running `py age.py` with the environment variable `PYLAUNCH_DEBUG` set:

```
launcher build: 32bit                                                                 
launcher executable: Console                                                          
Using local configuration file 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\py.ini'          
File 'C:\Windows\py.ini' non-existent                                                 
Called with command line: age.py                                                      
maybe_handle_shebang: read 256 bytes                                                  
maybe_handle_shebang: BOM not found, using UTF-8                                      
parse_shebang: found command: python                                                  
searching PATH for python executable                                                  
Python on path: C:\python34\python.EXE                                                
located python on PATH: C:\python34\python.EXE                                        
run_child: about to run 'C:\python34\python.EXE age.py'                               
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                    
  File "age.py", line 17, in <module>                                                 
    name = raw_input("Enter a person's name to check their age: ")                    
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined                                            
child process exit code: 1
```

Comment: Try using a shebang, `#!/bin/env python2.7` at the top of your script referring to the location of `Python27` ?

Comment: Set the environment variable `PYLAUNCH_DEBUG` to any value and run the script using `py my_file.py` in a Command Prompt window.  What output does this give you?

Comment: @ZdaR It's important for this specific script not to have a shebang.

Comment: @LukeWoodward Output is this: https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/ffb9425e05b232e723cd

Comment: @eryksun I've never installed Python 3.5, I think I got my launcher from Python 3.4.

Comment: @RamRachum, the similar behavior I thought I had with 3.5's launcher turned out to be unrelated. In 3.5 the launcher checks for and uses an active `VIRTUAL_ENV`. I had an active 3.4 virtual environment, which was overriding py.ini.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) describes this behaviour:

> The `/usr/bin/env` form of shebang line has one further special property. Before looking for installed Python interpreters, this form will search the executable `PATH` for a Python executable. This corresponds to the behaviour of the Unix `env` program, which performs a `PATH` search.

Oddly enough this same functionality appears to apply to Python 3.4 as well (or at least version 3.4.3), despite the [corresponding documentation page for Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/using/windows.html#shebang-lines) not mentioning it.  I've included a reproduction of this behaviour at the bottom of this answer.

It seems your script contains the shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top, and `C:\Python34` is on your system's `PATH` before any appearance of `C:\Python27`.  You say in a comment that

> It's important for this specific script not to have a shebang

but the line

```
parse_shebang: found command: python
```

in your launcher output gives away the fact that the script must indeed have a shebang line.

---

I have Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.4.3 installed on my system, with 3.4 before 2.7 on the `PATH`. I also have a `py.ini` file in `C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local` which contains the following:

```
[defaults]
python=2
```

and a `test.py` script that contains

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys; print(sys.version_info)
```

I've set the value of the environment variable `PYLAUNCH_DEBUG` to `1`.  Running this script using `py test.py`, I get the following output:

```
launcher build: 32bit
launcher executable: Console
Using local configuration file 'C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\py.ini'
File 'C:\WINDOWS\py.ini' non-existent
Called with command line: test.py
maybe_handle_shebang: read 60 bytes
maybe_handle_shebang: BOM not found, using UTF-8
parse_shebang: found command: python
searching PATH for python executable
Python on path: C:\Python34\python.EXE
located python on PATH: C:\Python34\python.EXE
run_child: about to run 'C:\Python34\python.EXE test.py'
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=4, micro=3, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
child process exit code: 0
```

If I change my `test.py` script to

```
#! python
import sys; print(sys.version_info)
```

(i.e. remove the `/usr/bin/env` from the shebang line) and re-run `py test.py`, I get the following:

```
launcher build: 32bit
launcher executable: Console
Using local configuration file 'C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\py.ini'
File 'C:\WINDOWS\py.ini' non-existent
Called with command line: test.py
maybe_handle_shebang: read 48 bytes
maybe_handle_shebang: BOM not found, using UTF-8
parse_shebang: found command: python
locating Pythons in 64bit registry
locate_pythons_for_key: unable to open PythonCore key in HKCU
locate_pythons_for_key: unable to open PythonCore key in HKLM
locating Pythons in native registry
locate_pythons_for_key: unable to open PythonCore key in HKCU
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python27\python.exe is a 32bit executable
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python27\PCBuild\python.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python27\PCBuild\amd64\python.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python34\python.exe is a 32bit executable
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python34\PCBuild\python.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.
locate_pythons_for_key: C:\Python34\PCBuild\amd64\python.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.
found configured value 'python=2' in C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\py.ini
search for default Python found version 2.7 at 'C:\Python27\python.exe'
run_child: about to run 'C:\Python27\python.exe test.py'
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=10, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
child process exit code: 0
```

Comment: Solid reasoning, but it doesn't work even after removing the shebang line. Debug output here: https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/b2f5e086a7adaeaf5cbd

Comment: @RamRachum, but now your debug output says it can't find py.ini: "`File 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\py.ini' non-existent`". But it "`found configured value 'python=3' in environment`", i.e. the environment variable `PY_PYTHON=3` is set.

Comment: @eryksun Sorry, my mistake probably, but now I made sure that the file exists and still it doesn't work: https://gist.github.com/cool-RR/adbd67d87944a5971f0e

Comment: @RamRachum, you still have `PY_PYTHON=3` set. That overrides py.ini.